# Vaadin app is deployed on WildFly in Openshift, but i can see only standard openshift welcome page

Tags: java, maven, openshift, vaadin, wildfly

I'm a newbie with all that vaadin, wildfly and openshift stuff, so, please, excuse me, if I will sound stupid.

I deployed my app to Wildfly 10 server. Everything was fine during deployment. But now I just can't see the rendered page (only welcome page can be accessed).

When I deploy locally I use maven-wildlfly-plugin and I can reach the application on localhost:8080/client-1.0-SNAPSHOT/. Unfortunately the same pattern doesn't work with openshift deployment. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.vaadin</groupId>
<artifactId>client</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Client application built on Vaadin</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-java-ee-essentials</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId> 
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>        
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/au.com.bytecode/opencsv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.bytecode</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>client</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>v4.tahvonen.fi</id>
        <url>http://v4.tahvonen.fi/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And the starting rendered vaadin class looks like this (I don't use web.xml here):

```
@CDIUI("")
@Theme("valo")
public class VaadinUI extends UI {}
```

Please, advice, how to set up the url to access the application (not welcome page). Thank you in advance.